# Download file in ADF works for the first time only

Tags: java, jsf, oracle11g, download, oracle-adf

I have an `ADF` Table in `JSF` page that is bounded to `View Object` which holds user's uploaded files. This `View Object` contains all the information needed to download a file like `blob domain` , `file type` and `file name`. For each row there is a download button that enables the user to download the selected file.

Every things works perfectly for the first time. Problem is when the user press the download button for some file he/she already download it, the file get corrupted. The file appears in the download section for browser, but when I tried to open it tells that the file can not be open because the file format or file extension is not supported.

**here is the button in the `JSF` page:**

```
<af:column id="c31">
<af:commandButton text="Download" id="cb12" partialSubmit="true">
      <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{ITDetalisBean.downloadSelectedFile}"
         filename="#{row.FileName}" contentType="#{row.FileType}"/>
</af:commandButton>
</af:column>
```

As you can see the button is placed in `<af:column>` tag. So for each file row there is corresponding download button.

**Here is the `Bean` method:**

```
    public void downloadSelectedFile(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream) 
{
    // get the view object from the application module
    AppModuleImpl appM = (AppModuleImpl)(JSFUtils.getApplicationModule("AppModuleDataControl"));
    ViewObject fileUploadedVO = appM.findViewObject("UplodedFilesViewTransient1");

    // get the file content as blob domain from the current row
    BlobDomain blobDomain=(BlobDomain)fileUploadedVO.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("FileContn");


    // download the file using output stream
    try {
        HttpServletResponse response =
            (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        InputStream in = blobDomain.getBinaryStream();
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, count);
        }

        in.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        facesContext.responseComplete();


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved by adding the following:**

```
blobDomain.closeInputStream();
blobDomain.closeOutputStream();
```

at the end of `try`  block before the last statement `facesContext.responseComplete();`

**Minor Change:**

I was getting the `outputstream` by this line: `outputStream = response.getOutputStream();`

Instead I should use the `outputstream` that's come with method as an argument:

`public void downloadSelectedFile(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream)`

Comment: Tick your own answer to indicate that it got resolved.

Comment: @Ravinder I am not allowed till tow days more.

Comment: I also think that facesContext.responseComplete(); is not necessary, since the outputstream is given to you!